# mips: funtion to store string in heap

Tags: string, mips, heap-memory, mars-simulator

I've been trying to make a function to store a string (passed as parameter to a function) into the heap and make it return the memory address where it's saved. For that, I've made a loop iterating into every char of the string and putting it into an allocated byte. However, I receive the message  "invalid program counter value: 0x00000000"

This is what I have so far, any ideas on what might be wrong?

```
main:
    #Parameters for function
    #a0 (string)
    #a1 (string size)
    
    la $a0, string
    lw $a1, size
    
    jal saveString

    #Registers planification:
    #s0: string copy
    #s1: where space is saved
    #s2:  index pointer for the loop
saveString:
    sw $fp, ($sp)
    sw $ra, -4($sp)
    sw $s0, -8($sp)
    sw $s1, -12($sp)
    sw $s2, -16($sp)
    move $fp, $sp
    addi $sp $sp -20
    
    move $s0, $a0
    
    #allocate memory
    li $v0, 9
    move $a0, $a1
    syscall
    
    bltz $v0, saveString_noMemory
    
    #save pointer with $v0
    move $s1, $v0
    
    #initialize array pointer
    add $s2, $zero, 0

    jal saveString_Loop
    
saveString_Loop:
    beq $s2, $a1, saveString_End

    lbu $t0, ($s0)      #take value of string
    sb $t0, ($s1)       #inserto that value into one bit of allocated memory
    
    addi $s0, $s0, 1    #point to next char of the string
    addi $s1, $s1, 1    #point to next byte of allocated memory
    
    addi $s2, $s2, 1    #i++
    
    move $v0, $t0
    
    b saveString_Loop
    
saveString_NoMemory:
    #todo: error message
    jr $ra
    
saveString_End: 
    lw $fp, ($sp)
    lw $ra, -4($sp)
    lw $s0, -8($sp)
    lw $s1, -12($sp)
    lw $s2, -16($sp)
    move $sp, $fp
    
    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a calling convention error. You're saving $ra into the stack but not restoring it after you finish a function. Remember that jal will overwrite $ra. So when you do

```
jal saveString
```

you will no longer be able to return to the original function using jr $ra until you restore $ra by loading from the stack.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I thought that that's what I was doing when I wrote `sw $ra, -4($sp)` at the beggining of saveString and `lw $ra, -4($sp)` at the beggining to saveString_End, however now I see that it's not the case. Could you tell me how to proceed to restore $ra then? Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to move the stack pointer before you save to the stack, if you move the stack pointer after you save the stack you will essentially lose that data unless you move it back. If the stack is at let's say 0xFFFF and you save your $ra to that, and then move the stack down to 0xFFF0, when you `lw $ra, -4($sp)`, you will load from the new $sp. Move stack down to make space, move stack up after restoring.

Comment: Basically you need to move `addi $sp, $sp, -20` up before you save to stack. Also its courteous to other functions to do the opposite instruction after the function is finished but before you return. `move $sp, $fp` is not in line with calling convention.